# Doing a reverse MATCH lookup in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match

I have two tables.

`Data` and `GroupLookup`

`Data` contains Two fields `Text` and `Group`, GroupLookup contains `LookupValue` and `Group`

The idea is i wan't to use a formula for `Data[Group]` to find in `Data[@Text]` i.e. a row, a wildcard word from `GroupLookup[LookupValue]` and get `GroupLookup[Group]` into `Data[Group]`

For example i have a text called "Banjo Pizza 1231" in my `Data[Text]` i want to lookup "pizza" and then apply the `GroupLookup[Group]` whos value would be "Pizza Expense".

I've tried a formula like

```
=INDEX(GroupLookup[Group];MATCH("*"&[@Text]&"*";GroupLookup[LookupValue];0))
```

But it do it the wrong way. It applies the Text to the LookupValue. E.g "BC" in Text would match "ABC" in LookupValue. I want it the otherway around.

Comment: Provide some sample data and expected result.

Comment: What is the other way around?

Comment: How is it supposed to know that it should return *Pizza Expense* based on *Pizza* and not *Music Lessons* based on *Banjo*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please bear with my ASCII-art table:

```
      A                      B            C          D               E
   1          **Data**                               **GroupLookup**    
   2 Text                   Group                  LookupValue     Group
   3 Banjo Pizza 123        Pizza Expense          Pizza           Pizza Expense
   4 CrabbyPatty Burger     Burger Expense         Burger          Burger Expense
   5 Fries Work             Fries Expense          Fries           Fries Expense
   6 Softdrinkersss         SoftDrinks Expense     Softdrink       SoftDrinks Expense
   7 Pizzaderia             Pizza Expense           
   8 OverloadedFries        Fries Expense           
   9 Coco Koala Softdrinks  SoftDrinks Expense
```

Let's assume that the above data is your DataSheet, (with "A to E" as your column head and "1 to 9" is your row number) You should have a minimal data in the GroupLookup since it is your "Group". In my sample, I had grouped 5 categories in my "GroupLookup": Pizza, Burger, Fries, & Softdrink.

Then I will Lookup those value in my Data[Text] column using the below formula in Data[Group] column.

```
=IF(IFERROR(MATCH("*"&$E$3&"*",A3,0),"False"),INDEX($E$3:$F$6,1,2),IF(IFERROR(MATCH("*"&$E$4&"*",A3,0),"False"),INDEX($E$3:$F$6,2,2),IF(IFERROR(MATCH("*"&$E$5&"*",A3,0),"False"),INDEX($E$3:$F$6,3,2),IF(IFERROR(MATCH("*"&$E$6&"*",A3,0),"False"),INDEX($E$3:$F$6,4,2)))))
```

If the word Pizza is present in my Data[text] column, my Data[Group] column will get it's value from GroupLookup[Group] which is "Pizza Expense"; same logic with the other LookupValue.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following formula

```
=LOOKUP(2^15;SEARCH(Table2[LookupWord];[@Phrase]);Table2[Group])
```

[image]

I apply the formula to the to the `Group` column column B.

Comment: This solution follows the conventional method of looking up a substring in a larger string. The [LOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/lookup-function-df82ce98-edf9-46ea-8189-b0470e5e0e93) or [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) with wildcards would each accomplish this. I gathered from your description that you wanted to look up each split word from the string to match one of a set of substrings; hence *reverse* lookup. So it doesn't seem that this follows the directive of *' I want it the otherway around.'*.